# Convert HMAC Hash in C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php

So I am struggling with this code. I am trying to write a function in PHP that would effectively do the same thing as this method in C#:

```
private string CalculateSignature(string apiKey, string secretKey, long timeStamp)
    {
        // Generate the hash
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        HMACMD5 hmac = new HMACMD5(encoding.GetBytes(secretKey));
        byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(apiKey + timeStamp));

        // Convert hash to digital signature string
        string signature = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        return signature;
    }
```

This is all I have so far:

```
function calcSignature($apiKey, $secrekKey, $timeStamp)
{
    $retval = hash_hmac('md5', $secrekKey, $apiKey . $timeStamp, false);

    return $retval;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Concatenation in PHP is done with the `.` operator.

Comment: @TimCooper That's true, I did try it that way originally. I'll edit my question to reflect that. Thank you!

Comment: I had it pointed out to me that I may have the sequence of the hash_hmac wrong, so I flipped that to no avail: $retval = hash_hmac('md5', $apiKey . $timeStamp, $secrekKey, false);